# String.charCodeAt Max Length

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, base36, fromcharcode

Take this code:

```
var charCode = unkownVariable.charCodeAt(0);
```

What is the max length that `charCode` can be?  All my tests turned out as 2 character (2 digits).  Will it ever be longer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.5):

> Returns a Number (a nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>16</sup>) representing the code unit value of the character at position `pos` in the String resulting from converting this object to a String. If there is no character at that position, the result is `NaN`.

So, 2<sup>16</sup> - 1 is the maximum value, which is `65535`.

Comment: Interesting. So the smallest, single-byte representation of the highest character code (with native JS decode support) would be: `1ekf` (`(65535).toString(36)`)

Comment: Is there any way, we can access this 2^16 - 1 (the maximum value, which is 65535) ? For example, for numbers we have Number.MAX_VALUE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rashmi: I'm not aware of a built-in constant representing that value, but if you know it then you can create your own constant.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

```
var unkownVariable = 'test';
var charCode = unkownVariable.charCodeAt(0);
console.log(charCode); // 116
```

There are 16 bits used to display characters (there are different languages and charsets to consider), so the response theoretically could be anywhere between 0 and 65536 (2^16).

Answer (score 1):

MDN says

> Note that charCodeAt will always return a value that is less than
>   65,536.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt